# CSS: Set max-height to same value as height becomes when "none" max-height?

Tags: css, animation, height, dropdown, transition

So I am making a dropdown that uses transition of max-height and opacity, for example if the dropdown was 500 pixels in height, I would use 500px for max-height when open, and 0 when closed. However, my dropdown's height is auto calculated. I need to set max-height to this auto calculated height, so that the transition has correct timin. Otherwise, if I used a larger max-height value, when being closed the dropdown would not move until max-height had transitioned below the true value, and then suddenly move faster for the remaining time. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution. I just set the `maxHeight` to the `offsetHeight` before triggering closing of my dropdown.

I also needed to use `setTimeout` of 0 milliseconds for triggering closing it though after running the below function.

```
export function retreatDropdown(e: HTMLElement) {
  e.style.maxHeight = `${e.offsetHeight}px`;
}
```

I could do a similar trick for opening animation, but you won't know the correct `maxHeight` until it is opened, so my guess this is more tricky (but less important than closing animation IMO).

EDIT: Complete (TypeScript) solution for both closing/opening dropdown

```
const defaultTransitionTime = 200;

export function toggleDropdown(
  e: HTMLElement,
  value: boolean = null,
  toggleAction: () => void = null // Function that toggles true/false for accordion open
) {
  if (value) {
    openDropdown(e, toggleAction);
  } else {
    retreatDropdown(e, toggleAction);
  }
}

export function openDropdown(
  e: HTMLElement,
  openAction: () => void = null
) {
  if (openAction) setTimeout(() => openAction(), 0);
  e.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(() => {
    const offsetHeight = e.offsetHeight;
    e.style.maxHeight = "0px";
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.style.maxHeight = `${offsetHeight}px`;
    }, 5);
  }, 5);
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.style.maxHeight = "none";
  }, defaultTransitionTime);
}

export function retreatDropdown(
  e: HTMLElement,
  closeAction: () => void = null
) {
  e.style.maxHeight = `${e.offsetHeight}px`;
  if (closeAction) setTimeout(() => closeAction(), 0);
}
```

Dropdown CSS class:

```
.dropdown {
  transition: opacity 200ms linear, max-height 200ms linear;
  will-change: opacity, max-height;
}
```

Angular ngStyle (applied on open/close of accordion):

```
elementStyle(e: HTMLElement) {
    return this.isOpen(HTMLElement) // I use a map of booleans for open state here...
      ? { display: "block", "max-height": "none" }
      : { "max-height": 0, opacity: 0 };
  }
```